# Why is TypeScript not warning when setting a non-nullable value as null?

Tags: typescript

I am specifying types on a function. TypeScript types are (as of current TypeScript versions) non-nullable by default. However I don't get any errors when I run a function with `null` or `undefined`.

```js
function sayHello(name: string){
  console.log(`Hello ${name}`)
}
```

In the code above `sayHello(undefined)` and `sayHello(null)` should both fail.

What they currently do in TypeScript 3.8.3:

```
Hello null
Hello undefined
```

vsCode gives no warnings:

[image]

**Why is TypeScript not warning when setting a non-nullable value as null?**

Comment: TypeScript types are not nullable by default.

Comment: Try it. `sayHello(undefined)` logs `Hello undefined`

Comment: Also @BenBotvinick I've read that TypeScript types were nullable by default. it looks like this changed at some point: see "TypeScript originally started out with the idea that types were always nullable. " at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-2-0/

Comment: Maybe your compiler is misconfigured. Try adding the "strict" option. Also, try throwing a number into the function because if it is accepting null and undefined it's probably accepting other incorrect types, and that would mean your compiler is definitely misconfigured.

Comment: Also, if you read one second further you would find "TypeScript originally started out with the idea that types were always nullable. This meant that something with the type number could also have a value of null or undefined. Unfortunately, this didn’t provide any protection from null/undefined issues. In TypeScript 2.0, null and undefined have their own types which allows developers to explicitly express when null/undefined values are acceptable. Now, when something can be either a number or null, you can describe it with the union type number | null."

Comment: Show your tsconfig.json please

Comment: @BenBotvinick lol I did read further. That's exactly why I wrote a comment saying that nullable by default had changed. You're replying to me repeating the point I just made.

Comment: I've edited the question to more accurately reflect the situation and help others that have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a `tsconfig.json` file? If so, how does it look like?

Make sure, you have following entries in your `tsconfig.json` (shortened for the sake of brevity):

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

From the TypeScript doc:

`strictNullChecks`: switches to a new strict null checking mode.

Comment: Ah I can see that [`strict` is a superset including `strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: @mikemaccana Correct, so unless you want to activate all the strict type checking options listed there at once, you can simply go one by one as per your need. :D

Answer (score 2):

Not nullable is now the default in TypeScript. You should get the typescript compilation error:

```
Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. ts(2345)
```

If you don't get that, you may want to take a look at your compiler options. I would recommend the `strict` option.

You can set that up with a `tsconfig.json` file containing something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: Using typescript 3.8.3, running `sayHello(undefined)` does not warn.

Comment: What's not what I get. VSCode gives no compilation errors. `ts-node` runs the `.ts` file with no warnings or errors and prints `Hello null`

Comment: IMHO, `ts-node` is not a good tool. I recommend getting used to using `tsc` and running the compiled version through `node`. `ts-node` often obfuscates problems.

Comment: Thanks @klas I needed the `strict` option