# How to catch undefined after conditional?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tslint

Consider following example:

```js
function myFunc (b: number): string {
  let a: { c: any }

  if (b < 20) a = { c: 100 }

  console.log(a.c) // depending on 'b' this may throw error
  return 'ok'
}
```

I want my linter to tell me about this particular problem - that variable *may* be undefined. What rules should I use?
I tried: no-undef, no-undef-init, no-undefined and no-use-before-define

Comment: Probably relevant: [Why is TypeScript not warning when setting a non-nullable value as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60889805) - if you enable `strictNullChecks` or better yet - `strict`, then TS will give you an error.

Comment: This already throws a TypeScript error: https://tsplay.dev/wRlgxm

Comment: @TobiasS. unless strictNullChecks is disabed: https://tsplay.dev/NVkvGm

Comment: You shouldn't use TSLint. It was deprecated in 2019 and is not updated or maintained for one or two years..

Comment: Thanks, guys! I had some weird stuff going in my typescript linter settings