# Returned of undefined permitted in function that does not allow undefined returns

Tags: typescript

...at least as far as Intellisense highlighting goes. Why is this line not highlighted?
[image]

When changing the return of undefined to a string, highlighting DOES kick in. Note eventually I want to change the functions possible return types to Question | undefined but I want to make sure I'm sane with this highlighting.

EDIT: Minimal reproducible example, can be copy-pasted into VSCode.

```
export class Question {
    public text:         string
    public ans_options?: Array<boolean> | Array<string> | Array<number>
    public ans?:         boolean | number | string

    constructor(text:         string,
                ans_options?: Array<boolean> | Array<string> | Array<number>,
                ans?:         boolean | string | number) {
        this.text        = text
        this.ans_options = ans_options
        this.ans         = ans
    }

    // No highlights of the badness of this function in IDE.
    public static noHighlightedFunction(...args: Array<any>): Question {
        console.log(args)
        return undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: So is this question about TypeScript...? Or the editor highlighting gone awry?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlighting" here, exactly?  Are you talking about *error* highlighting?  That is, you expect to see an error at `return undefined`?  If so then you should probably [edit] to not make it seem like an IDE issue; you're actually concerned about tsc not producing expected errors.  I suspect you don't have `--strictNullChecks` enabled and if you enable it (or just `--strict`) the issue will resolve.  Is that what's going on?

Comment: @jcalz you solved this. Thank you! If you want to comment I will mark as answer.

Comment: Probably should be marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889805/why-is-typescript-not-warning-when-setting-a-non-nullable-value-as-null